# SCEP Protocol on Linux

Tags: linux, certificate, protocol

Is it possible to setup an SCEP protocol on Linux?  My company is going to be adopting over-the-air enrolling for iPads and I can't find anything for this on Linux.  Has anyone done this before?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know anything specific about SCEP on linux but I just want to give you one advice.

Some years ago we tried to do the same with Netscreen (now Juniper) routers and Microsoft PKI  (target was a VPN infrastructure). We abandoned the idea after some tests because we found that certificates were correctly distributed at the beginning but the system was not working for certificates renewal at all (we also opened a case in Microsoft). Fortunately we found it before deploying it in production, so my advice is: double check every aspect (also revoke and renew part) before deploying anything...